# Update columns with equal values in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simplified table like this:

```
id | title            | note
----------------------------------
 1 | Lorum Ipsum      | some note
 2 | Lorum Not Ipsum  | some note
 3 | Lorum Ipsum      | another note
 4 | Lorum Ipsum      | some note
```

I am using the following statement:

```
UPDATE table
SET title = 'newTitle'
WHERE title = (SELECT title FROM table WHERE id = 1) 
AND note = (SELECT note FROM table WHERE id = 1)
```

But I am getting "ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED".

If I provide id=1, it should update the title of the rows with id=1 and id=4

How do I update columns with equal values in the same table by only providing an id?

Comment: which dbms , is it mysql?

Comment: yes mysql, i added the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not allow you to use the table being updated in a subquery in an `update` or `delete`.
you can use `join` instead.

```
UPDATE Table1 T
JOIN ( select title,note from Table1 where id =1) NewT
on T.title = NewT.title 
and T.note = NewT.note
SET T.title = 'newTitle'
```

Comment: `+1`. join is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table
   SET id=1, title='newTitle'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       title = VALUES(title);
```